# validating uniqueness within a has_many through

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, validation, has-many-through

I have a `User` that can have many `Restaurants`. I can also have multiple users.

I'd like to have it so that if **User A** creates **Restaurant A**, he should ***NOT*** be able to make another restaurant with the same name.

However, if **User B** goes to create **Restaurant A**, that should be allowed but still cannot make *another* **Restaurant A** afterwards.

I have the following `has_many through` relationship:

**restaurant.rb**

```
has_many :ownerships
has_many :users, :through => :ownerships

# This following ensures uniqueness of the name within the 
#   Restaurants table regardless of who the User is that created it.
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :ownerships
has_many :restaurants, :through => :ownerships
```

**ownership.rb**

```
belongs_to :restaurant
belongs_to :user
```

---

### What I've Tried

**1. Adding :uniqu => true**

I've tried adding :uniq => true to the restaurant.rb file so it looks like this:

```
has_many :ownerships
has_many :users, :through => :ownerships, :uniq => true
```

And removing `uniqueness: true` from the validation so it looks like this:

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

But that doesn't do anything useful.

**2. Adding validation within ownership.rb**

I've tried adding the validation to the `ownership.rb` file as such:

```
validates :restaurant, uniqueness: {:scope => :user}
```

But I get:

```
NoMethodError in RestaurantsController#create
undefined method `text?' for nil:NilClass
```

And I can't seem to tell it to look for the restaurant name within the scope of user either within this validation.

**3. Creating before_create callback function**

In my `restaurant.rb` file, I declared the following:

```
before_create :check_uniqueness

def check_uniqueness?
  user = User.find_by_id(self.user_ids)

  isUnique = false
  user.restaurants.each do |restaurant|
    if !Restaurant.find_by_name(self.name).nil? # Restaurant w/ same now found
      isUnique = false
    else
      isUnique = true
    end
    return isUnique
  end
end
```

My assumption is that before the restaurant record is created, it'll do this `check_uniqueness` check and if the function returns false, it'll not save.

But I'm getting the following error when I hit the submit button:

```
NameError in RestaurantsController#create
undefined local variable or method `check_uniqueness' for #<Restaurant:0x007f95a16d10f8>
```

---

### Working Solution

Thanks to [Robert Chuchro's help below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763973/1393002), I was able to get the validation to work. Here's what I did:

**restaurant.rb**

```
before_create :unique_per_user?

def unique_per_user?
  user = User.find_by_id(self.user_ids)
  restaurant = user.restaurants.find(:all, :conditions => ["name = ?", self.name])

  if restaurant.size > 0
    self.errors.add(:name, ": You've already created a restaurant with this name.")
  end

  return (restaurant.size <= 0)
end
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your current code? Where exactly are you stuck? What error do you encounter?

Comment: @Jocelyn I've updated my post above to show some of the things I've attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to define a method to do this in your restaurant model

```
def unique_per_user?
  #get user trying to create restaurant, either by paramter or association
  #check if any of the user's current restaurant names match this name (return true/false)
end
```

now whereever you define a new restaurant check if its unique_per_user? before deciding to save it.

Comment: I attempted what you said but I'm getting an error. I've updated my original post. Could you see #3 under the 'What I've Tried' section and give me some pointers? Thanks!

Comment: You need the question mark ? in before_create :check_uniqueness?